# Ajax form automatically sent with Rails3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial called 'follow_form', which is displayed in another one called `player_infos`.
I'm displaying `_player_infos`in `players#show" .

My problem is that when I go to `players/show` , a relationships is automatically created. I mean, the form in `players/_follow`is automatically sent.

This `follow_form`partial contains :

```
  <% unless current_user == @player %>
  <div class="follow_form">
      <% if current_user.following?(@player) %>
        <%= render 'players/unfollow' %>
      <% else %>
        <%= render 'players/follow' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My `_follow`:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @player.id),
             :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Suivre" , :class=>"grid_13 cursor" %></div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT

Ok so I have to precise that my RelationshipsController contains :

```
     def create
    @player = Player.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@player)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @player }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And `follow!`refers to :

```
 class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

   def follow!(followed)
    relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
  end

  end
```

So, I can't understand why the relationship is created even if i don't click on the submit button .

Tell me if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the form is automatically submitted?

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for the `build()` method of the collection of a `has_many` relationship states the following:

> Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been
>   instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a
>   foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

The changes haven't been saved to the database, but the in-memory objects have a relationship set up between the two players.

You could try to just create the object directly, instead of using the `relationship` collection to do so, and once the form is submitted to then create it using the `relationship` collection.